# Lamé's equation - elliptic PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, computational-mathematics

I have a specific PDE in 3-dimensional space + time (the right one). u(x,t) is the unknown function (values are in R^3) and F(x,t) the right hand side, mu and lambda are positive constants.

### [image: Lamé's equation]

Now consider the stationary case of the right equation, that means the term with the time derivate goes zero. I have to show now that the stationary case leads to an elliptic linear PDE of 2'nd order.
The problem is the term ∇(∇.u) = grad(div(u)). If i write it out, the component-functions of u appear everywhere. For exampe the first component of the PDE reads:

-μ[u1_(1,1) + u1_(2,2) + u1(3,3)] - (μ + λ)[u1_(1,1) + u2_(1,2) + u3(1,3)] = F1(x,t)

with notation: u1_(i,j) as the second order derivative of the first component-function of u in directions j and i.

So i can't write this equation in standard form to get a Matrix A, which has to be symmetric and positive definit for the PDE to be elliptic - since i can only scale the the vectors u_(i,j) with some scalars a_ij in standard form.

Does anyone has an idea what i'm supposed to do?

I would be glad for some help! Thank you!

Comment: You can try to prove $(Lv,v)\geq \alpha \|v\|^2_H$ for any $v\in H$, where $H$ is the domain of $L$.